# Why doesn't the AI bool flag preserve through the next page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The player can select a 1P or AI mode for this game. We are simply keeping track of it using a flag. However, if we change the flag to true on click, it goes back to the default false when we route to the next page. For example:

Walkthrough: User would choose the mode they want to play - AI or 1P. Then, they click play which will bring them to a page to choose a topic. After choosing a topic, they will be routed to the respective AI or 1P game page.

```
var ai = false;

$('.mode').click(function() {
     ai = !ai;
     $(this).text(function(i, text) {
        return text === 'Select Mode: AI' ? 'Select Mode: 1P' : 'Select Mode: AI';
    });
});

$('.states').click(function() {
     // TODO flag engine to grab words from the states word bank
     if (!ai) {
        location.href = 'game.html';
      } else {
        location.href = 'roboGame.html';
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of your script that sets `var ai = false` is running every time you load a page with this script. Try using browser localStorage.

```
var ai = localStorage.getItem('ai-flag') || false;

// before navigating to next page
localStorage.setItem('ai-flag', ai);
```

or for a safer solution you can use query params when routing:

```
// on load
var ai = /ai=true/.test(location.search);

// on redirect
location.href = 'index.html?ai=' + ai;
```

Benefits of the second solution include being able to deep-link to a particular state!

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

if you plan to use _ancient_ browsers, this won't work. Another option might be cookies.

Comment: good point, its always good to be aware of feature availability. strictly speaking cookies and localstorage will both fail in certain scenarios, even in modern browsers, based on user configuration. another suggestion might be using a query parameter, which is very, very fool-proof. i've added an example to my answer.